# Cover up logistics pipes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

After getting the basics of my base up and running with logistics pipes, I want to tidy up and cover up what I can. Am I able to cover up logistics pipes at all? I tried using the covers I can make using a saw, but I can't place it around the pipe, I can only place it on the next block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeah, Logistic Pipes (and other BuildCraft  pipes) don't work with Forge Multiblocks.

You need [BuildCraft Facades](http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Facades). You can craft them in an assembly table by tossing 3 Structure Pipes and 1 block of the desired type which will give you 6 facades.

Structure pipes are made by crafting a gravel block and a cobblestone pipe together.

Comment: Ahh, I completely forgot about the facades (I'm still new to FTB). I'll do that later on when I get in, cheers :).